# Parameter Binding in CodeIgniter 3.1 Query Builder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a query

```
$column = 1234;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql,[$column])->row();
```

which works completely fine
But when i have union clause i have to pass the parameter twice

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN = ?
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN = ?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql,[$column,$column])->result();
```

Do we have something like below code to achieve the above result where i could pass only one value since both of them requires same value.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN = :column
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN = :column";
$result = $this->db->query($sql,['column' => $column])->result();
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));  You cannot pass a single param...

Comment: You have written same type of query as I have have in my second code, but how do I achieve the third code.

Comment: Hello there is a syntax mismatch according to DB platform please refer this link [ https://www.databasestar.com/sql-bind-variables/ ]

Answer (score -1):

Well you can just use :

```
$column = 1234;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN = " . $column . "
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN = " . $column . ";
$result = $sql->result();
```